# Formatting json to fit what i need or a better way of doing it

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hello there I have an array in php which and then a json_encode function which outputs

```
{
"Machine": {
    "cycle": 4230.7,
    "percent": 73.26
},
"cycle": 6.63,
"percent": -0.45
}
```

I need it to output like this example below or an alternative way to get the elements out of json

here is the ideal json formatting and the code to go with it

```
var text = '{"Machines":[' +
'{"cycle":"10","percent":"10" },' +
'{"cycle":"20","percent":"20" },' +
'{"cycle":"30","percent":"30" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.Machines[1].cycle+ " " + obj.Machines[1].percent;
```

Below is the way i have the array setup in php

```
$Cycle = array(
 "Machine" => array(
    "cycle" => $machine1->Data(),
    "percent" => $machine1->GetM()
),
    "cycle" => $machine4->Data(),
    "percent" => $machine4->GetM()
```

I would like to know the best way writing the array to fit the example json format or a better way to to get the cycle and percent values out of the json formatting  currently have thanks

Comment: I am using  var machines = <?PHP echo json_encode($Cycle); ?>; to get the json in the first place, and the json that comes from the array does not seem to work with the code that posted in the mid section of my question

Comment: Yes I understand, the code I posted will however work with that :) http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/FCR88/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following structure will give you the correct format:

```
$Cycle = (object) array(
    'Machines' => array(
        (object) array(
            'cycle' => $machine1->Data(),
            'percent' => $machine1->GetM()
        ),
        (object) array(
            'cycle' => $machine2->Data(),
            'percent' => $machine2->GetM()
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Why cast them all to objects?

Comment: Because they are objects, look at the expected json.

Comment: Try this and you'll see why it's unnecessary: `<?php $array = array('machine' => array('cycle' => 12.34,'percent' => 0.56)); print json_encode($array);`

Comment: It's not what is expected. In your case "machine" is an object, not an array.

Comment: Then he can add an array of items and it will work. Casting is not necessary: http://pastebin.com/8LZK7AUf

Comment: I think the OP just needs valid JSON but perhaps I'm wrong. You have the same sentiment as me by realising that `Machines` is meant to be a collection, be it a collection of arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the JSON to text and then use JSON.parse() to read it back, just use the JSON!

PHP:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'machine' => array(
        array(
            'cycle' => 12.34,
            'percent' => 0.56,
        ),
        array(
            'cycle' => 56.78,
            'percent' => 0.56,
        ),
    )
);

print '<script>var foo = ' . json_encode($array) . '</script>';
```

JS:

```
console.log(foo.machine) // shows the array
console.log(foo.machine[1].cycle) // shows 56.87
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $Cycle = array(
     "Machines" => array(
        array(
            "cycle" => 'cycle1',
            "percent" => '70.34'
        ), array(
            "cycle" => 'cycle4',
            "percent" => '20.34'
        )
      )
    );

    echo json_encode($Cycle);
```

will output this:

```
{"Machines":[{"cycle":"cycle1","percent":"70.34"},{"cycle":"cycle4","percent":"20.34"}]}
```

which when prettyfied:

```
{
    "Machines": [{
        "cycle": "cycle1",
        "percent": "70.34"
    }, {
        "cycle": "cycle4",
        "percent": "20.34"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, hadn't seen that until I posted but since it isn't technically the same and even expands I don't think it's a warranted DV!